# A multiple choice question on factorising polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the polynomial $f(x)= x^4-x^3+14x^ 2 + 5x+16$. Also for a prime $p$, let $\mathbb F_p$ denote the field with $p$ elements. Which of the following are always true?

1. Considering $f$ as a polynomial with coefficients in  $\mathbb F_3$, it is a product of two irreducible factors of degree 2 over $\mathbb F_3$.
2. Considering $f$ as a polynomial with coefficients in  $\mathbb F_7$, it has an  irreducible factor of degree 3 over $\mathbb F_7$.
3. $f$ is a product of two polynomials of degree 2 over  $\mathbb Z$.

I don't know how to factorise a polynomial over $\mathbb F_p$. Is there any algorithm to do so?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 7\!:\  f(x) \equiv x^4\!-x^3\!-2x+2 \equiv (x-1)(x^3\!-2),\: $ and $\rm\:a^3\!\equiv 2\:\Rightarrow 1\equiv a^6\equiv 4\:\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

Answer (score 1):

1) False as $x=2$ is root, so not possible to write as product of irreducible factors of degree $2$.